# Why cant I make query call on Factory but I can on Controller? Angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular-resource

```
angular.module('app').factory('mvsomeManager', 
 function ($q, $http, mvSomething){
    return{
        getsomedata:function(){
            var data = mvSomething.query();
            if(response){
              dfd.resolve(response);
            }else{
                dfd.reject({reason:"error"});
            }
            return dfd.promise;//No data is returned
    };
 });
//usage
angular.module('app').controller('mvsomelCtrl', function ($scope, mvsomeManager,mvSomething){
    //same thing in factory but now it returns list without problem
    $scope.querydata = mvSomething.query();//This works
    $scope.querydata = mvsomeManager.getsomedata();//This does not works!
 });
```

Can you not call query on a factories? I am able to call Delete, put, etc on Factories using the $save,$update. but just cant use GET (query) to return a list of data. Only works on controller.

Comment: You do have extra code in there and you are not returning the resulting data. If you want more help you need to provide working code or explain what `dfd` and `response` are as you do not define them in your code sample (*downvote was not me*).

Comment: `getsomedata` returns a promise. Once its resolved you will have your data, whatever `response` is. Use `.then/.catch` etc to handle it. Look at angulars [promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q). Pretty much the same syntactically to ES6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one operation that is synchronous (`query`) and the other (`getsomedata`) is deferred.  So you need to use `.then()` to access the data.

```
//this call is synchonous
$scope.querydata = mvSomething.query();//This works
//this call is async 
mvsomeManager
       .getsomedata()
       .then(onGetDataSuccess, onGetDataError);

function onGetDataError(error){
    alert('error, please check console logs');
    console.error(error);
}

function onGetDataSuccess(data){
    $scope.querydata = data;
}
```